# Long press textmenu editing

Tags: applications

I am very new to apply codes. Sorry my disturbunce...

I am english learner. I am reading english newspaper. When i long press on a word textmenu popup and i need to push translate button but its in hidden side and i need to press three dot to open it.

How can i find this textmenu area in an app on apk editor?
How can i get long press menu fixed in view on an app.
Or at least how can i change order long press menu copy,share, select all to other order..
Thank u in advance. Any mistake please delete my message and forgive me...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change this order because Android devices this order internally.

Answer (score 0):

As Aashish points out, it's Android itself that presents this menu, not the app. The app can add extra items to the "three dots" menu, but it can't move items into the first menu or change the order. Instead, you should look for a *custom ROM* (a modified version of Android with this feature), or an Xposed plugin that lets you change the menu. I don't think the feature you want exists in either of those forms.

One alternative is provided by the Google Translate app itself. It has an option called **Tap to Translate**. This option makes it listen in for text copied to the clipboard. When you copy some text, Google Translate pops up a button to translate it immediately. You might find this a little easier than using the **Translate** option from the menu.

To activate this option, go to the Google Translate app. In the navigation drawer (the *hamburger menu*), go to **Settings**, then **Tap to Translate**. Flick the **Enable** switch on.